# Silly Ada Generic Package Management?

Tags: ada

I have just started using Ada, and I'm finding the generic package declarations to be rather silly. Maybe I'm not doing it right, so I'm looking for better options.

Take a look at the below example.

```
package STD_Code_Maps is new
   Ada.Containers.Map(Key_Type     => STD_Code_Type;
                      Element_Type => Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String);
STD_Code_Map : STD_Code_Maps.Map;

-- . . .

procedure Do_Something is
   Item : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
begin
   Item := STD_Code_Maps.Element(STD_Code_Maps.First(STD_Code_Map));
   -- Do something with the Item
   -- . . .
end Do_Something;
```

It would be much cleaner to simply be able to write `STD_Code_Map.First.Element` instead of the godforsaken `STD_Code_Maps.Element(STD_Code_Maps.First(STD_Code_Map));`

Obviously I'm doing this wrong -- I think. I'm repeating the phrase STD_Code_Map at least thrice over there. I'm all for verbosity and everything, but really the code I'm writing seems bad and silly to me.

I was wondering if there is solution that doesn't **require** you to rename the package to something like `package Map renames STD_Code_Maps;` which would of course shorten the code but I don't want to do this on each and every procedure entry. I really think something like `STD_Code_Map.First.Element` would be much simpler. Can this be done in Ada 2012?

Note: Using the Unbounded_String package by default is also so difficult. Did the standard library designers actually give much thought to the ridiculous and overly long package hierarchy?

Thanks for reading this, and potentially helping me out. I'm new to Ada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNAT GPL 2012 and 2013, and FSF GCC 4.7 and 4.8, support the new container indexing scheme of Ada 2012, which means that you can write

```
Item := STD_Code_Map ({some Cursor});
```

And you can do this even with the `-gnat05` switch to force Ada 2005 mode! (which has to be a bug).

Ada 2005 allows you to call a primitive function of a tagged type using `object.function` notation, provided that the first operand is of the tagged type; so you can write `STD_Code_Map.First` as shorthand for `STD_Code_Maps.First (STD_Code_Map)`.

Putting these together, you can write

```
Item := STD_Code_Map (STD_Code_Map.First);
```

which is quite short!

Answer (score 4):

The issue has nothing to do with generics.  As Simon pointed out, you *can* say STD_Code_Map.First, since the type of STD_Code_Map is a tagged type and Ada supports this notation for tagged types.  On the other hand, the type of STD_Code_Map.First is a Cursor type, which isn't tagged (making it tagged would have caused problems declaring certain operations that take both a Cursor and a Map).  But even without the Ada 2012 container indexing that Simon mentioned, you can say

```
STD_Code_Maps.Element(STD_Code_Map.First);
```

which is a little better.  Besides renaming a package, you can also rename the function:

```
function Elem (Position : STD_Code_Maps.Cursor) return STD_Code_Maps.Element_Type
    renames STD_Code_Maps.Element;
```

and you can now use just `Elem` instead of `STD_Code_Maps.Element` wherever the renaming is directly visible.  (You could call it `Element` if you want to.  The renaming name can be the same or it can be different.)  This could be helpful if you use that function a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Ada was designed for readability and maintainability. (written once, read & maintained for much longer) This means that it does get a little verbose at times. If you prefer terse & cryptic there are plenty of other languages out there !

If you want to avoid typing STD_Code_Map all the time, just use a `use` clause:

```
use STD_Code_Map;
```

which would mean your code of

```
   Item := STD_Code_Maps.Element(STD_Code_Maps.First(STD_Code_Map));
```

would become

```
   Item := Element(First(STD_Code_Map));
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not possible. I have a use clause for a Vector in my procedure, because that's the thing I'm using most. Vector.Cursor and Maps.Cursor clash. The code will not compile until I make it clear that First(...) is returning type Cursor for Maps package... not Vector package. I have to use STD_Code_Maps.First() to make things clear to the compiler

Comment: Then i think a renaming would be the best option. `package SCM renames STD_Code_Map;` should make life easier.

Comment: I guess I'll go with that for now. Coming from a C/C++ background is certainly a hindrance when learning Ada. One simply would do `vector<my_type> a; item = a[0];` I think you can understand that writing `item = vector<my_type>.element(vector<my_type>.first(a));` feels sooo wrong. Very wrong indeed. Sigh. I think C++ really wins over here.

Comment: Ada will reward you if you get into its mindset properly. IMHO the worst Ada code i have seen is when people are trying to write Ada with a C/C++ compiler.

Comment: I see. Anyway thanks for the answers. I'll stick with the Ada way of doings things for this project I'm working on. I have everything I need (ARM 2012 and GNAT 4.8 + man pages). Finding out that Enumerations don't work the C way was a huge shocker, I just resorted to using constants. That made bitwise operations easier. I'll probably stick around for a few days to clear up any questions. Thanks. P.S. Can you really write Ada with a C++ compiler?

Comment: Nvm, figured it out--it was a tick. Umm, how do I set this question as answered? Sorry, my first time here.

Comment: No you cant, but have seen people mangle Ada code to 'look' like the c-style they are used to!

Answer (score 3):

Getting names nice and readable in Ada can sometimes be tricky. Often times language designers made the task worse than it had to be, by designing Ada standard library packages for use with Ada `use` clauses, without a thought to how they'd look to some poor sap who either can't or doesn't want to use that feature.

In this case though, there are things you can do on your own end.

For example "_Maps.Map" is redundant, so why not get rid of it from the package name? Why not use names so that you can write:

```
package STD_Code is new
   Ada.Containers.Map(Key_Type     => STD_Code_Type;
                      Element_Type => Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String);
Map : STD_Code.Map;

-- . . .

procedure Do_Something is
   Item : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
begin
   Item := STD_Code.Element(STD_Code.First(Map));
   -- Do something with the Item
   -- . . .
end Do_Something;
```

Now `Code` looks like a bit of a null-meaning word too. *Everything* in a program is a code. So I'd consider ditching it as well. Unsually I name my Ada container packages something that says their basic theoretical function (eg: `STD_to_String`), while objects are more specific nouns.

Also, I should point out that if your map is constant and you can live with names that look like identifiers, often times you can get rid of maps to strings entirely by using an enumerated type and the `'image` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ada 2012 the `STD_Code_Maps.Element(STD_Code_Maps.First(STD_Code_Map));` could become:

```
Function Get_First( Map : STD_Code_Maps.Map ) return Unbounded_String is
( STD_Code_Maps.Element(Map.First) );
```

That is an example of the new Expression-functions, which were mainly introduced for pre- and post-conditions.

Of course, if you're using Ada 2012 then the precise map you'd likely want is `Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Ordered_Maps` -- the Indefinite_* containers are those that [can] have indefinite elements, like `String`.

---

In addition to TED's comment, using an enumeration when the maps are constant have even more advantages, namely case coverage: the compiler will flag as an error any case-statement that doesn't cover all alternatives. So if you add a new code it will flag all the case-statements that you need to modify. (Of course this benefit is lost when you use the `others` case.)